# Listview with custom BaseAdapter, items created out of screen takes values from first items

Tags: android

I have a listview with custom adapter. It's pretty simple, each item has a checkbox and textbox. However the issue is, when you check a checkbox and scroll down, some list items are automatically checked outside of screen too.

For example if you check first 2 items and scroll down; first 2 items out of screen comes checked too. How to fix this?

Here is my adapters getview method:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.share_item, parent, false);
        }

        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkboxShare);

        TextView tvShareName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvShareName);


        tvShareName.setText(shareList.get(position).getName());



        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: use Array Adapter instead of Base Adapter string see this http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/listview-with-checkboxes-without-listactivity.php

Answer (score 0):

Read the definition of `convertView` parameter. When this method is called and `convertView` is not null - your code will change the value of the `TextView`, but will keep the value of `CheckBox` intact. The net effect is that once `CheckBox` gets checked, it will remain so and whenever this `View` gets recycled you'll have it checked.

The simple solution would be to set the value of `CheckBox` inside this method.

Offtopic: you might want to read about View Holder (anti) pattern - I don't like it very much, but performing `findViewById` calls on each invocation of `getView` is even worse.